# Cannot create an instance of class error when trying to create a ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

Currently my activity class looks like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FamiliarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val noticeScreenViewModel : NoticeScreenViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FamiliarTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val currentBackStack by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = currentBackStack?.destination
                val currentScreen =
                    familiarScreens.find { it.route == currentDestination?.route } ?: Settings

                FamiliarNavHost(
                    noticesViewModel = noticeScreenViewModel,
                    navController = navController,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NoticeScreenViewModel looks like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NoticeScreenViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val noticeRepository: NoticeRepository
) : ViewModel(){
    val notices: List<Notice> = noticeRepository.getNotices()

}
```

NoticeRepository looks like this:

```
class NoticeRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val noticeDao: NoticeDao
) {

        fun createNotice(notice: Notice) {
            noticeDao.insert(notice)
        }

        fun removeNotice(notice: Notice) {
            noticeDao.delete(notice)
        }

        fun getNotices() = noticeDao.getNotices()

        companion object {

            // For Singleton instantiation
            @Volatile private var instance: NoticeRepository? = null

            fun getInstance(noticeDao: NoticeDao) =
                instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                    instance ?: NoticeRepository(noticeDao).also { instance = it }
                }
        }
}
```

NoticeDao looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface NoticeDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notice")
    fun getNotices(): List<Notice>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg notices: Notice)

    @Insert
    fun insert(notice: Notice)

    @Delete
    fun delete(notice: Notice)

}
```

And it never, ever works. Every time, the app crashes at the initialisation of the ViewModel. Yes, I have tried everything I've found in similar posts. What am I missing?

I have remade all of these classes several times and never got past the step of creating a viewModel.

stack trace:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dmlpcb.familiar, PID: 27627
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.dmlpcb.familiar.ui.NoticeScreenViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$noticeScreenViewModel$2.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:23)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$noticeScreenViewModel$2.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:22)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity.getNoticeScreenViewModel(FamiliarActivity.kt:22)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity.access$getNoticeScreenViewModel(FamiliarActivity.kt:19)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:36)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:28)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:360)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.compose.ThemesKt.FamiliarTheme(Themes.kt:22)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:28)
at com.dmlpcb.familiar.FamiliarActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(FamiliarActivity.kt:27)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:195)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
2023-12-29 00:35:46.765 27627-27627 AndroidRuntime          com.dmlpcb.familiar                  E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:158)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3340)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3273)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:588)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1013)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:520)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1191)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:183)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1266)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21980)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3014)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
2023-12-29 00:35:46.776 27627-27627 AndroidRuntime          com.dmlpcb.familiar                  E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.dmlpcb.familiar.ui.NoticeScreenViewModel. []
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
... 92 more

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the crash? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Described in the post title, it's way too long to include in full in a reply @ianhanniballake

Comment: No, you need to add the full stack trace as part of your question.

Comment: I've noticed that the app doesn't crash if the constructor for the viewmodel takes no parameters, but that's obviously not useful.

Comment: Your stack trace indicates that Hilt is not running at all in your Activity (otherwise you'd see Hilt's ViewModel Factory in the stack trace). Can you confirm you've followed the [Quick Start guide](https://dagger.dev/hilt/quick-start) and annotated your Application class as a `@HiltAndroidApp`? If you want to add your Application class to your question, we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring your viewModel like this: `private val noticeScreenViewModel : NoticeScreenViewModel by viewModels()` do it in your Composable like this: `val noticeScreenViewModel : NoticeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()`.

Like this:

```
FamiliarNavHost(
      noticesViewModel = hiltViewModel <noticeScreenViewModel>(),
      navController = navController,
      modifier = Modifier.padding()
)
```

Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation) for an example.

Also, you did not show your **AppModule** or your **Hilt Application** file. Maybe that's missing?

Comment: that did not work

Comment: I've added an example.